# How to display a messagebox from the click of a button C# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I created a button on a small app I'm building and can't use MessageBox.Show b/c I am using Web not Windows. Does anyone know how I can get my message to display using C#?

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox is for Windows apps.  Use JavaScript for message boxes in web apps.  `alert('hello world');`  The C# code is processed on the back end by the web server, which doesn't show message boxes to the end user.  JavaScript is processed by the browser which does show message boxes to the end user.  You have to use JavaScript to show a message box to the user.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Exactly, which is why i said i can't use it. I figured that. not a pro in javascript. Do you know what code i would use?

Comment: it does. but i don't know what code to use.

Comment: `alert('hello world');`

Comment: alert doesn't exist in the current context is the error msg i'm getting. I'm using C# as code behind of an ASP.Net website.

Comment: See this page for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx.  Put `alert` in the <script> block instead of the `Form1.Message.value`